# Symfony 2 : creating web, admin, api modules with normal & social logins

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to Symfony and Doctrine. I want to build a new system. I've got some basic understanding of the framework and in below I have mentioned that the ways I chosen to build this system. I want to know that am I going in the right path? or do I have to use other ways to implement these features? .Thanks

- Sub-systems : **Web Frontend**, **Admin Backend** and **RESTful API**

> Current scenario is to build **4 bundles** ; **Core**(as a service layer), **Web**, **Admin** and **API**(for mobile apps). Hope to use controllers on Core Bundle on other Bundles.

*can I use one bundle for Core and Web modules?*

- Authentication : **Web** and **Social** logins

> Current scenario is to use **FOSUserBundle** and then integrate it with **HWIOAuthBundle**

- RESTful API

> Current scenario is to use **FOSRestBundle**

can I follow same above methods or are there any better ways to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Symfony. I want to know that I have to follow above methods or I have to use another ways to implement this perfectly. Thanks